babel-plugin-styled-components works well with NODE_ENV=development but not with NODE_ENV=production in React app
I am facing the following situation in my React App. I use babel-plugin-styled-components. When NODE_ENV!==production classes are generated and injected in the head tag and used by the React components. But when NODE_ENV===production the same classes are generated and injected in the head tag, but the components do not use them, but other diferent classes not defined, so styles are not applied.


As you see from the picture, the same classes defined with NODE_ENV!==production are injected in the head tag, but the component (div tag), uses a className not defined in the head tag (or anywhere), so styles are not applied. As I say, when NODE_ENV!==production this doesn't happens and the components uses the classes defined and injected in the head tag.
If anyone has a clue of why this happens and how to solve it would be very much appreciated by me. Thanks in advance.
This is the babel.config.js:
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-styled-components"]
}

I use rollup as a bundler.
Thank you!!!

For anyone facing the same situation as described above, here is how I solved it. The problem was with this configuration in the rollup config file:
      alias({
        entries: [
          {
            find: "styled-components",
            replacement: "styled-components/dist/styled-components.js",
          },
          { find: "@", replacement: path.resolve(__dirname) },
        ],
      }),

commenting the part of styled-components fixed the issue:
  alias({
    entries: [
      // {
      //   find: "styled-components",
      //   replacement: "styled-components/dist/styled-components.js",
      // },
      { find: "@", replacement: path.resolve(__dirname) },
    ],
  }),

Hope this can help anyone else. Thanks.
